# Cast Python class to parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `class A`. I need to store an additional value on `class A` so I extend it, creating `class B` which includes a `my_variable` attribute. I have a load of code that uses `class B`, but at the end of that code, I **need** to return a `class A` object.
How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear without seeing your code and with this description why you can't just do `return A()`.

Comment: A `B` *is* an `A` so there should be no reason you can't just return your `B`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: It seem that your simplified description is oversimplified. Add more details

Comment: All those comments make sense as far as my understanding, but my colleague is insisting it needs to be a particular class... At least this is useful as a sanity check.. If I can find out some more details and adjust my question I will. Otherwise I guess this is resolved - in the example I've given, this shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, a `class B` object is a `class A` object:

```py
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
b = B()
print(isinstance(b, A)) # True
```

It will even pass type annotations this way. There is no need to cast the object, because it already is an instance of the parent class.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with duck typing; as you note, it will pass static type analysis, and the behavior is exactly the same in languages that are strongly typed by default.

Comment: This is my understanding too - so I think there must be another reason outside the scope of this question why it "needs" to be of the parent class. This discussion was useful as a sanity check though!